# Node.js Write failed: Broken pipe after stdout

Tags: node.js, ssh, broken-pipe

When ever I run my node.js server I only get one chance to test my code. Then there after i get a write failed: broken pipe this is really annoying as i have to re log back in and and run the server again..

I don't care for forever node at the moment because I want to observe the output from the console or any errors.

Can one help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your ssh config file..

For Linux : /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
For MacOSx :  ~/.ssh/config for Mac:

Prefixes:

ClientAliveInterval 120
ServerAliveInterval 120